# How to structure class for deserializing this nested array?

Tags: java, android, json, kotlin, gson

I'm trying to deserialize a nested array from a JSON response. It's the first time I've ever gotten an array of arrays and I'm not quite sure how to structure my class to handle it.

```
{
"prices": [
            [
                1641670404234,
                0.01582586939240936
            ],
            [
                1641674037525,
                0.015999047707867396
            ],
            [
                1641677655158,
                0.016072905257982606
            ]
            
            ...
         ],
}
```

If the brackets were `{` instead of `[`

```
{
"prices": {
            {
                1641670404234,
                0.01582586939240936
            },
            {
                1641674037525,
                0.015999047707867396
            },
            {
                1641677655158,
                0.016072905257982606
            }
           }
            ...
}
```

I could use

```
@SerializedName("prices")
private List<Price> prices;
```

```
public class Price {
    private long date;
    private BigDecimal price;
}
```

However since it is `[` instead, I am quite unsure how to structure it.

I've tried adding another `List` wrapper to it but that throws an error

```
@SerializedName("prices")
private List<List<Price>> prices;
```

```
IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was NUMBER at line 1 column 26 path $.prices[0][0]
```

I've also tried wrapping it with a `JSONArray`

```
 @SerializedName("prices")
private List<JSONArray<Price>> prices;
```

but that's not quite right

[image]

I've tried searching other SO answers but I could not find any examples where it's two consecutive `[ [` brackets.

They are all `{ [` or `[ {`.

What's the correct way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming this is the correct JSON:

```
{
    "prices": [
        [
            1641670404234,
            0.01582586939240936
        ],
        [
            1641674037525,
            0.015999047707867396
        ],
        [
            1641677655158,
            0.016072905257982606
        ]
    ]
}
```

Then you can use this model to deserialize data to:

**JAVA**:

```
public class PricesModel {
    public ArrayList<ArrayList<Double>> prices;
}
```

**KOTLIN**:

```
data class PricesModel (

  @SerializedName("prices" ) var prices : ArrayList<ArrayList<Double>> = arrayListOf()

)
```

Handy JSON converters to [Java](https://json2csharp.com/json-to-pojo) and [Kotlin](https://json2kt.com).

Comment: The Kotlin class is incorrect (probably due to a bug with the used code generator), the property type should be `ArrayList<ArrayList<Double>>`.

Comment: thanks @Marcono1234 for noticing.

Answer (score 2):

The proper way to solve this is to write a custom [`TypeAdapter`](https://javadoc.io/doc/com.google.code.gson/gson/latest/com.google.gson/com/google/gson/TypeAdapter.html) for your `Price` class. This has the advantage that you can keep your model classes as is (with a `List<Price> prices` field), and have them represent more closely the actual data. If instead you parsed the JSON data as `List<List<BigDecimal>>` or similar, then you would have to manually validate that the JSON data is wellformed and have to convert the `List<BigDecimal>` to a `Price` object yourself.

Here is how a `TypeAdapter` implementation for your `Price` class could look like:

```java
class PriceTypeAdapter extends TypeAdapter<Price> {
    @Override
    public void write(JsonWriter out, Price value) throws IOException {
        out.beginArray();
        out.value(value.date);
        out.value(value.price);
        out.endArray();
    }

    @Override
    public Price read(JsonReader in) throws IOException {
        in.beginArray();

        Price priceObj = new Price();
        priceObj.date = in.nextLong();
        // nextString() automatically converts JSON numbers to String, if necessary
        // This is similar to how Gson's default adapter for BigDecimal works
        priceObj.price = new BigDecimal(in.nextString());

        in.endArray();

        return priceObj;
    }
}
```

Note: Alternatively to reading the `BigDecimal` manually as shown here, you could create this type adapter inside a [`TypeAdapterFactory`](https://javadoc.io/doc/com.google.code.gson/gson/latest/com.google.gson/com/google/gson/TypeAdapterFactory.html) and get the default Gson adapter for `BigDecimal`. This allows reusing Gson's built-in adapters inside your own type adapter, but here for `BigDecimal` that overhead is probably not worth it.

You can then either [register your adapter on a `GsonBuilder` instance](https://javadoc.io/doc/com.google.code.gson/gson/latest/com.google.gson/com/google/gson/GsonBuilder.html#registerTypeAdapter(java.lang.reflect.Type,java.lang.Object)) or you can place an [`@JsonAdapter`](https://javadoc.io/doc/com.google.code.gson/gson/latest/com.google.gson/com/google/gson/annotations/JsonAdapter.html) annotation on your `Price` class, which references the adapter. In case you use the `GsonBuilder` approach, you might want to create a `null`-safe variant of your adapter by calling [`nullSafe()`](https://javadoc.io/doc/com.google.code.gson/gson/latest/com.google.gson/com/google/gson/TypeAdapter.html#nullSafe()) on it (or you implement `null` handling in the adapter manually).

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to write this. I very much appreciate it